# error: expected class name (linked list c++)

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, nodes

I'm supposed to create a linked list (asked to put everything for now in header file) and I am trying to create a struct for nodes but it says it needs a class name. What did I do wrong? I am a bit confused on using a struct to create nodes for the list.

```
#include "LinkedListInterface.h"

#ifndef LAB03LINKEDLIST_LINKEDLIST_H
#define LAB03LINKEDLIST_LINKEDLIST_H


template <typename T>
class LinkedList: public LinkedListInterface<T>
{
public:    // this is where the functions go
    LinkedList();
    void AddNode(T addData)
    {
        nodePtr n = new node;
        n->next = NULL;
        n->data = addData;

        if (head != NULL)
        {
            current = head;
            while (current->next != NULL)
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = n;
        }
        else
        {
            head = n;
        }
    }
    void DeleteNode(T delData);
    void PrintList();
private:
    struct node:
    {
    T data;
    node* next;
    };
    typedef struct node* nodePtr;
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr current;
    nodePtr temp;
};



#endif //LAB03LINKEDLIST_LINKEDLIST_H
```

Comment: Remove the colon (`:`) after `struct node`

Comment: Because this is template code you should put everything in the header file. If you ever try to move it out of the header file that would be a mistake.

Comment: You already have the response from @Yksisarvinen . But also your #include should be inside the #ifndef LAB03LINKEDLIST_LINKEDLIST_H block, not outside. This can reduce considerable the time of compile.

Comment: Is `AddNode` declared as `virtual void AddNode(T) = 0;` in the CRTP class `LinkedListInterface`?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node:
{
    T data;
    node* next;
};
```

Should be

```
struct node
{
    T data;
    node* next;
};
```

There is no `:` after a class name unless you intend to use inheritance - @john

Comment: Unless you are intending to use inheritance (which is probably what confused the OP).

Comment: Thank you friends!